# Critical Sections and Memory Fences / Barriers on a multi-processor system

Tags: c, memory-management, thread-safety, windows

I have a Windows DLL (in C) that uses Critical Sections. A specific routine, which is called numerous times, needs to perform some initialization code the first time it is called, so I am using a Critical Section. However, since it is called so many times I am trying to avoid the overhead of entering the section each time it is called. It seems to be working, but I am wondering if there is a flaw considering memory barriers / fences when running on a multi-processor (Intel) system with an x64 OS? Here is the stripped down code:

```
int _isInitialized = FALSE;
CRITICAL_SECTION _InitLock = {0};

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    ARM_SECTION_BEGIN(ul_reason_for_call)

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case (DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH):
        InitializeCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
        break;
    case (DLL_THREAD_ATTACH):
        break;
    case (DLL_THREAD_DETACH):
        break;
    case (DLL_PROCESS_DETACH):
        DeleteCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
        break;
    }
    return (TRUE);
}

int myproc(parameters...)
{
    if (!_isInitialized)        // check first time
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
        if (_isInitialized)        // check it again
        {    
            LeaveCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
            goto initialized;
        }
        ... do stuff ...
        _isInitialized = TRUE;
        LeaveCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
    }
initialized:
    ... do more stuff ...
    return(something)
}
```

Comment: Consider replacing `... do (more) stuff ...` with some equivalent, yet simple code so others may compile and test.  You are the best judge of _equivalent simple code_.

Comment: You have mentioned the OS, yet not the compiler of interest.  Recommend to tag with that _compiler_.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Re: _doing stuff_ it can really be anything that is typically done once but should not be done in `DLLMain`, such as `LoadLibrary` for other DLLs.

Comment: I didn't realize that the compiler would make a difference. `InitializeCriticalSection`, `EnterCriticalSection` and `LeaveCriticalSection` are all imports which (I think) would be unaffected by the compilter, How would building it differ under Visual Studio 2008 vs 2010 vs 2017? I have all three.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate for this question to be on StackOverflow?

Comment: "How would building it differ under Visual Studio 2008 vs 2010 vs 2017?" --> IDK.  Yet code would certainly have trouble compiling with gcc.  Added V-S tag as that is the compiler of your interest..  "Would it be more appropriate ... on StackOverflow?" --> it looks like a reasonable question on SO  too.  Suggest if the post here does not garner the needed feedback after a few days, try there.

Comment: `EnterCriticalSection`, being a Windows function, should work on any configuration of CPU(s) Windows runs on. You probaly should declare `_isInitialized` as volatile to make sure every thread sees any change another thread made to its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... if there is a flaw considering memory barriers / fences ... ?

**Use [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/12a04hfd(v=vs.140))**

Code certainly appears to risk using a stale value for `_isInitialized` in the 2nd test.

```
if (!_isInitialized) {
  EnterCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
  if (_isInitialized)                 // Risk
```

To insure a re-read of `_isInitialized`, use `volatile`.  [@JimmyB](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208954/critical-sections-and-memory-fences-barriers-on-a-multi-processor-system?noredirect=1#comment403772_208954)

```
// int _isInitialized = FALSE;
volatile int _isInitialized = FALSE;
```

**Other Shared Data**

Other data than `_isInitialized` assigned in the `... do stuff ...` and used in the later `... do more stuff ...` code risks the same problem due to an optimization may read `other_data` before the  the first `if (!_isInitialized)`.

Code could use `volatile other_data`.  Unfortunately that may incur an unacceptable performance drag.  Alternatives depend on what is inside `stuff`.

**Style**

I'd make `_isInitialized` local to the function, drop the `_` and avoid the `goto`.

```
int myproc(parameters...) {
  static volatile int isInitialized = FALSE;

  if (!isInitialized) {
    EnterCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
    if (!isInitialized) {
      // ... do stuff ...
      isInitialized = TRUE;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&_InitLock);
  }

  // ... do more stuff ...
  return(something)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion re: volatile. That didn't occur to me. But wouldn't that also apply to the CRITICAL_SECTION structure? I don't see any special attributes used in the definition for CRITICAL_SECTION in the header files. How are those prevented from becoming stale?

Comment: @NeilWeicher `CRITICAL_SECTION` is adorned with whatever attributes are needed in its declaration.  The compiler and library that define `CRITICAL_SECTION, EnterCriticalSection(), LeaveCriticalSection()` do what ever they do to get the job done.  `volatile` exists to prevent a highly optimizing compilers from skipping a read.  The compiler you are using works fine with its library.  The question here is: how to insure compilation works well with your code.  The VS complier may use features (or has well hidden them) for its library that your code cannot access.

Comment: On a related note, is there any limit to to size of what I can make volatile? For example, can I declare this? `static volatile HANDLE myHandle=NULL;`. Or even an array of HANDLES? `static volatile HANDLE myHandles[16]={0};`. And if so, would that have an impact on performance?

Comment: @NeilWeicher No limit.  When `volatile` not needed, performance is slower.

Comment: I wanted to see what the compiler was doing with the `volatile` keyword. So as a test I built the module (Visual Studio 2010) with `/FAcs` to generate Assembly, Machine Code and Source. I then built with and without `volatile`. The resulting COD files were exactly the same in both cases: `PUBLIC _isInitialized<br>_BSS SEGMENT<br>_isInitialized DD 01H DUP (?)`. So how is `volatile` being passed on?

Comment: @NeilWeicher Sorry `volatile` apparently is not helping much.

Comment: I did some more research on it. My misunderstanding. `volatile` does not affect the declaration, it affects the code optimization. For example, take this code: `static volatile BYTE _isInitialized = 0xFF; while (_isInitialized-- > 0);`. Without `volatile` the compiler might use a register to decrement the variable. With `volatile` it will decrement the memory location itself at each loop. btw - thanks for all the good replies.